# SQL Concat or LIKE with wildcard?

Tags: sql, sql-like, concatenation

The table includes two columns where one enumerates countries (name) and another capitals (capital). I need to find the country which name is included in its capital. For example country is Mexico and its capital is Mexico City. How is it possible to do using Concat or Like?

I have tried something like

```
SELECT name,capital FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE 'world.name&'
```

Also I have tried to go through concat

```
SELECT name,capital FROM world
WHERE capital=concat(name,'&')
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like homework. Did you try anything?

Comment: Would also need a bit more info, like what database you are using? Access, Mysql, MSSQL, oracle, etc?

Comment: Sorry, that's not the spirit of this website. Please read take the tour to understand how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!  I'd try:

```
SELECT name,capital FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE '%name&'
```

Answer (score 1):

Any of these should work:

```
SELECT name,capital FROM world WHERE capital LIKE '%name%'
```

or..

```
SELECT name,capital FROM world WHERE CONTAINS(capital,name)
```

or..

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%name%', capital) FROM world
```